# Trying to access a local file on a Flask application to call images through leaflet.js and Chrome returns: Not allowed to load local resource

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome, leaflet

I am working on a demo web application on air quality develloped with Flask that should work locally on my laptop. This application was deployed before but for several reason it was put offline and I am in charge to revive it with as little change to the original cede as possible (part of the project brief).

I manage to get most of the functionalities working but one of these functionalities an implementation of the [leaflet.js](https://leafletjs.com/) library that allow to display map queried though a link using the name of the file itself but the server in question is offline (query made by leaflet not the Flask back end).Therefore, I tried to requests the images stored into a local folder and to try to query them from there but every time I try to bet the image I get this error:

> Not allowed to load local resource

I am assuming that Chrome stops me to access my local file for obvious security reasons.

I tried the four different solutions found [here](https://www.minitool.com/news/not-allowed-to-load-local-resource.html) which are:

- Change DNS Settings
- Clear DNS Host Cache (since I run it locally bit of a wste of time)
- Look into installing Web Server Extension for Chrome but Chrome stopped to support it Decembre 2022
- Disable Security Settings in Chrome

I also tried to open Chrome,exe with CLIs as follow:

- path/to/Chrome.exe --disable-web-security --allow-file-access-from-files --allow-file-access
- I looked into using Google drive but it generate a hash code for each of the file andthis hash code changes evrytime that I would change the name of the file which make the implementation quite ahed scratcher

All of them alone or in different combinations did return the same ***Not allowed to load local resource*** message.

I would love to have a quick fix for it but it seem clear that I need a new setup for the images to be callable by filename (must be absolutely done this) and I cannot think of any myself.

This set up should allow me to:

- Store and call the image without the type of obstruction stated above
- Also I should be able to change the name of the files to keep up with the current timestamps inside the given set up as the demo data is 8 days worth of previously recorded data.

Also the use of the Flask's wsgi web server is a non-negociable.

Could you please let me know if any one knows a solution on my problem and please do not hesitate to ask if you have any question.
Thanks in advance.